# SQL - Joining a matrix based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoping someone can help me out here as I appear to being going around in circles as SQL isn't my strong point.
I'm at a loss if I can solve the problem with a join but I suspect not.

Problem:
Essentially I have a table and I need to match codes against a lookup table to see which codes are valid and which are not.

Table: tblMatrix

```
ID      family0 family1 family2 family3 family4
1000    AAALL   ZZZAA   11111   NULL    NULL
1001    AAALL   ZZZAA   11122   NULL    NULL
1002    AAALL   ZZZBB   11111   NULL    NULL
1003    AAALL   ZZZBB   11122   NULL    NULL
1004    AAARR   ZZZAA   11111   NULL    NULL
1005    AAARR   ZZZAA   11122   XXX11   NULL
1006    AAARR   ZZZBB   11111   NULL    NULL
1007    AAARR   ZZZBB   11122   NULL    NULL
```

The comparison is against the following table:
tblComparision

```
ID      code1   code2   code3   code4
4034    AAALL   11122   NULL    NULL
5555    AAARR   ZZZAA   NULL    NULL
6667    11122   AAARR
```

In a stored procedure, I am looping each row in the tblMatrix and essentially need to a count of if any combination of the codes exist in tblComparison.
So for example,   ID 1000 is valid as no combation exists.  However, ID 1001 is not valid as both AAALL and 11122 have occurred.

Note also that the codes may not be in the correct order so ID 1007 would not be valid as both AAARR and 11122 exist.

Any thoughts as to how I would achieve this.  Would several joins work?

The closest I've got to it working is below.  Essentially, it starts to fail when the I family1 isn't a match but not sure how to avoid this.

```
select * from tblMatrix2 as t1
join tblComparison as t2
on 
(t1.family0 = t2.code1  or t1.family0 = t2.code2  or t1.family0 = t2.code3 )
join tblComparison as t3
on
    (t1.family1 = t3.code1 or t1.family1 = t3.code2 or t1.family1 = t3.code3 )
join tblComparison as t4
on
    (t1.family2 = t4.code1 or t1.family2 = t4.code2 or t1.family2 = t4.code3 )
where t1.id = 10001;
```

Any help would or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably explain a little bit more what you want, Is it that you want to find the rows where all the non-null columns exists in any of the columns / rows of the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all values by making a `union` of the fields (no match will not be shown here):

```
 SELECT sub.id,
         CASE WHEN MAX (sub.cn) = 1 THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END status
    FROM (  SELECT fam.id, COUNT (lst.id) cn
              FROM    (SELECT id, family0 family FROM tblMatrix
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT id, family1 FROM tblMatrix
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT id, family2 FROM tblMatrix
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT id, family3 FROM tblMatrix
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT id, family4 FROM tblMatrix) fam
                   INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT id, code1 code FROM tblComparison
                       UNION
                       SELECT id, code2 FROM tblComparison
                       UNION
                       SELECT id, code3 FROM tblComparison
                       UNION
                       SELECT id, code4 FROM tblComparison) lst
                   ON fam.family = lst.code
             WHERE fam.family IS NOT NULL AND lst.code IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY fam.id, lst.id) sub
GROUP BY sub.id
ORDER BY id
```

Bonus info:
These union'ed lists transform your tables to something managable in sql with no repeating columns (like code1,code2 etc.). You could simply change the tables accordingly to have a better data model (whithout `NULL`):

```
create table tblMatrix (id int, family varchar2(5));
create table tblComparison (id int, code varchar2(5));
```

If you need to make family or code groups, just add a column for that.

Comment: You sir, are a star!  I'd been scratching my head on this for a long time.

Thanks for the bonus info as well.

Comment: Thanks. Note that the inner join removes all rows from tblMatrix, that has no match in tblComparison in the result.

Comment: Yeah, I've just been playing around with it.

The thoughts about breaking the tables down into something more manageable is actually more useful than you'd think.  Previously, I was attempting to create a table similar to the tblMatrix that had potentially 18^8 combinations!  In theory, I could have infinite codes in both tables!